# Consolidate Multiple Click Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, click

Sorry if the title isn't accurate. Not sure how to describe it properly.

I have this and it works great:

```
$(document).on('click', '.flrapPM01', function(event) { 
    toggleDiv('premiereModal01');
});

$(document).on('click', '.flrapPM02', function(event) { 
    toggleDiv('premiereModal02');
});

$(document).on('click', '.flrapPM03', function(event) { 
    toggleDiv('premiereModal03');
});
```

But I want to consolidate the above and put it into an external js file.

This is as far as I got:

```
function fireModal() {
    .on('click', '.flrapPM01', function(event) {toggleDiv('premiereModal01');});
    .on('click', '.flrapPM02', function(event) {toggleDiv('premiereModal02');});
    .on('click', '.flrapPM03', function(event) {toggleDiv('premiereModal03');});
}
```

And how do I make sure `'click'` works when touched on a mobile device?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few different ways you can easily do this.  With your current code, You can use a selector such as `'.flrapPM01, .flrapPM02, .flrapPM03'` or `'[class*=flrapPM]'` and then you can use a simple regex to extract the number from the class (e.g. `/(?!flrapPM)\d+/`).  Honestly, though, I'd look into using data attributes and passing the ID that way if you have control of the markup.  Anyway, here is a quick example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[class*=flrapPM]', function(event) { 
    var num = this.className.match(/(?!flrapPM)\d+/);
    toggleDiv('premiereModal' + num);
});

function toggleDiv(which) {
    alert(which);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="flrapPM01 btn other class">PM01</button>
<button class="something flrapPM02">PM02</button>
<button class="flrapPM03">PM03</button>
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you. I'm using the class because I wasn't sure if SharePoint would accept a data attribute. I thought about it but since SharePoint was stripping the script I was adding to the `<a>` I figured I'd try the class next to see if it worked, which it did. But I will definitely try the data attribute just to see (and learn). Thank you again. I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.